# RabbitMQ Load Balancing Across Multiple Consumers with Multiple Threads

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, rabbitmq

I'm fairly new to RabbitMQ and I've been tasked with fixing a load balancing bug that is occurring.

Here is the setup: 
We operate a Protobuf over RPC Api utilizing RabbitMQ.

A request to the api will be published to rabbit which will be then be consumed by one of 3 instances (the API is distributed across 3 instances of the application).

Each instance is set to utilize 10 threads to process the request and return a response. We accomplish this by setting a up a SimpleMessageListener with 10 ConcurrentConsumers which results in 10 corresponding threads that handles each message.

This results in:

```
Instance 1: Consumers 1-10, Instance 2: Consumers 11-20, Instance 3: Consumers 21-30.
```

Since Rabbit uses a round robin approach to distribute load across the consumers (vs distributing the load across the instances of the application) if 5 messages come through we end up seeing load like this:

```
Instance 1: Threads 1-5 in use (6-10 idle), Instance 2: Idle, Instance 3: idle.
```

What I want to have happen would be:
5 Messages:

```
Instance 1: Threads 1,2 in use, Instance 2: threads 1,2 in use Instance 3: Thread 1 in use.
```

In other words I would like to go round robin according to the instance (ex. Instance 1(consumer 1), 2(11), 3(21), 1(2), 2(12)) and not the consumer (ex. Instance 1, consumers 1-5).

Is this possible using Spring AMQP (1.2.1) and Spring Rabbit (1.2.1) libraries? My first thought is to reduce the concurrent consumers per instance down to 1 (so rabbit distributes evenly to each instance of the application) and then use an executor to spin up a thread for each request (up to 10 threads total per instance).

I haven't seen anyone else facing a similar issue so I'm hoping someone can give me some guidance! I'm mainly trying to see if I can do config changes to our current set up or if I'll need to implement something manually.

Thanks!

Comment: Not exactly what you was asked for, but I think it may be useful - https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-consistent-hash-exchange

Answer (score 4):

If you want to round-robin to your three servers, then I think that your thought (concurrent consumers = 1) to be the best option.

You should note though, that it's only as fair as the order in which the applications connect to listen for messages, for example:

1. app1 listens
2. app2 listens
3. message dispatched to app1
4. app1 listens
5. app3 listens
6. message dispatched to app2
7. message dispatched to app1 *** this is not round-robin here
8. message dispatched to app3

Without having some kind of *targeting* information inside your messages, your best effort is going to be as orderly as your processes connect to receive messages.

But if you go down to a consumer count of 1 and hand off the message to an executor and immediately listen for more messages, I would wager you would get a pretty even distribution.

I should also note, you're going to make ACK/NACK harder in this setup.  If you're using Java 8, the `CompletableFuture` API would fit nicely here to do some straightforward ACK/NACK from the handed off threads

Comment: Good answer! In addition I should say that all your instances should have the same concurrency. It does not look for me as good one: `11-20`, `21-30`. They should be `1-10` too. Another options to consider are `prefetch` and `transaction-size`. Even if they are `1` by default, they are options for each concurrent consumer. That's why your first app consumes all those 5 messages. Because for RabbitMQ each of them opens its own channel and they looks for Broker like separate consumers. So, round-robin works well there. Yes, having only `1` concurrency should help to distribute between apps.

Answer (score 1):

You can achive this behaviour with [consumer priorization](https://www.rabbitmq.com/consumer-priority.html). Just give every consumer on each instance a priorization from 1-10. Since documentation this should spread work load evenly.